# Visual Studio slow debugger - 30,000 lines of output

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

The debugger is slow, but only in 2012 and 2013 and only on some PCs. 2010 is fine, and 12 and 13 are fine on other systems. Each page takes about 50 seconds to load for a very simple web app and all postbacks are noticeably lagged.

At least part of the problem seems to be the AjaxControlToolkit's ToolkitScriptManager. Having it on a page adds 40 seconds to the load time. But even without it there's something laggy going on.

I've tried all kinds of slow debugger fixes. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

This error shows up in the debugger output roughly ten billion and a half times:

> Exception was thrown at line 2, column 84585 in
>   http: //localhost/site/ScriptResource.axd?d=x6wALODbMJK5e0eRC_p1LVVnaXgiyAu-eqoykp80Oxvk9nxuO5O0JHgNSWlQGDP3WkPk18-WLUd2nOxl3KK2gbeFfxQc1rj0x9uX4llm_wZE6X3CyXnmSwSSBu3veyOc0&t=ffffffffda74082d
>   0x8000000a - JavaScript runtime error: The data necessary to complete
>   this operation is not yet available.

I'm guessing just printing it all to the screen is time consuming

There's also this an unnecessary amount of times:

```
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/site-234-130591569422756007): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\site\e3795fac\389ade27\assembly\dl3\daf8a430\00f8c2a0_eef8ce01\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/site-234-130591569422756007): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\site\e3795fac\389ade27\assembly\dl3\97aa7394\70675ba1_eef8ce01\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/site-234-130591569422756007): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\site\e3795fac\389ade27\assembly\dl3\e8010163\d028d1a0_eef8ce01\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'w3wp.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/site-234-130591569422756007): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\site\e3795fac\389ade27\assembly\dl3\435711a2\307169a1_eef8ce01\AjaxControlToolkit.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
```

The debug output is now 30,000 lines for one click of the run button. it's loading and unloading dll's 1000's of times and filling the rest with javascript runtime errors.

Comment: delete all your breakproints

Comment: @OscarCabrero "Debug menu < Delete All Breakpoints" or `ctrl`+`shift`+`F9` default hot key

Comment: the problem seems to be part script loading and part dll loading. the debugger log shows it loading and then unloading 100+ dlls on every postback

Answer (score 2):

Try to move temporary files to a RAM disk.

In web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation tempDirectory="R:\">

       <!-- ... -->

    </compilation>
</system.web>
```

I use [SoftPerfect RAM Disk](https://www.softperfect.com/products/ramdisk/). It's freeware.

Good article on decreasing ASP.NET compilation time: http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2010/12/01/Slash-your-ASPNET-compileload-time.aspx